# Issue passing nested variable as parameter to ansible shell module

Tags: shell, syntax, ansible, yaml, runtime-error

I'm not able to figure out how I can pass a nested variable as parameter to Ansible's shell module & invoke the script "check.sh" however, below is what I tried.

```
---
- name: "Find the details here "

  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: set_fact
      set_fact:
        fpath_APP: "{{ fpath_APP + [ item.split('.')[0] ~ '/' ~ item | basename ] }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ Source_Files.split(',') }}"
      vars:
        fpath_APP: []

    - name: Invoke shell script

    - shell: "./check.sh {{ Number }} '{{ vars['fpath_' + Layer] }}' > hello.txt"

  tasks:
    - name: Ansible find files multiple patterns examples
      find:
        paths: /home/examples
        patterns: "*.db"
        recurse: yes
      register: files_matched

    - name: Search for Number in the matched files
      command: grep -i {{ Number }} {{ item.path }}
      with_items:
        - "{{ files_matched.files }}"
```

The above playbook runs but does not invoke the shell module and completes without doing anything. See Output below:

```
$ ansible-playbook fpath.yml  -e " Source_Filenames=/tmp/logs/filename1.src,/tmp/logs/33211.sql,/app/axmw/Jenkins/file1.mrt
Layer=APP Number=57550"  [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only
localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not
match 'all'

 [WARNING]: While constructing a mapping from fpath.yml, line 2,
column 3, found a duplicate dict key (tasks). Using last defined value
only.


PLAY [Find the details here]
**************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts]
******************************************************************************************************************************************************** ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP
******************************************************************************************************************************************************************** localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0   
failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Below are my failed attempts at changing the shell module syntax:

```
- shell: "./check.sh {{ Number }} '{{ 'fpath_' + vars[Layer] }}' > hello.txt"
```

Does not invoke Shell module

```
- shell: "./check.sh {{ Number }} '/"{{ vars['fpath_' + Layer] }}/"' > hello.txt"
```

Gives Syntax Error.

```
- shell: "./check.sh {{ Number }} /"'{{ vars['fpath_' + Layer] }}'/" > hello.txt"
```

Gives Syntax Error.

I'm on the latest version of ansible and python version is 2.7.5.

Comment: `[WARNING]: While constructing a mapping from fpath.yml, line 2,
column 3, found a **duplicate dict key (tasks)**. Using last defined value
only.` This clearly indicates that the playbook you pasted is not the one you are running. Yours contains a duplicate `tasks` entry which is empty and this is why no tasks are played (or you are including the posted playbook in an other one with `include_tasks` rather than `include_playbook`). There are other potential problems in your tasks but fix that first and try to go further.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I have now added the complete playbook which still fails. Any solution would be great!! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `vars` lookup plugin: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/vars.html

For your example, above you would want to do:

```
- shell: "./check.sh {{ Number }} {{ lookup('vars', 'fpath_' + Layer) }}" > hello.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, however this has syntax error. Also, if you look at my playbook the second parameter to check.sh has to be in single quotes ''. I tried :     - shell: "./check.sh {{ Number }} '{{ lookup('vars', 'fpath_' + Layer) }}' > hello.txt" but it gives error: ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.        - name: Invoke shell script
      ^ here

Comment: I removed the duplicate task entry and this works with ``` - shell: "./check.sh {{ Number }} '{{ lookup('vars', 'fpath_' + Layer) }}' > hello.txt". Thank you @Mark Loeser for the pointer!!